# Is it possible to use the android API through C level? or can I use the Codec through C code?

Tags: android, c, video, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

I am building a video system, which contains video capture from camera, video encode and video mux.

I want to use the encode in C level, since there is some algorithm I want to implement before the data is sent to the encoder.

There is a 'native-media' project in NDK samples, in which it calls OMX functions in C level to do the video decode and play stuff, but it seems that NDK doesn't support encode of OMX now, is that true?

I've successfully used MediaCodec API in Java level, if NDK doesn't support encode of OMX, can I use the MediaCodec API through C code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, from C code you can call Java methods.
For example, if we want to call the method x.doSomething(5), supposing x is an instance of class MyClass in the "com.example.ndk" package and the method returns void, we can use:

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/ndk/MyClass");

jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "doSomething", "(I)V");

(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, x, mid, 5);
```

Where:

- "env" is the JNIEnv pointer which you receive in the C JNI method (read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html) for information about the JNIEnv pointer and native methods).
- "(I)V" is the method signature, which in this case it says that the method has an int parameter (I), and returns void (V).
- "x" is a jobject obtained in some previous *env function ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) you can find all of JNI functions pointed by env).

Comment: Thank you! That would help, I suppose. Anyway, my initial intention is like this: There are corresponding C functions to the Java Api in Android, can we call these C functions?

Comment: No, you can't directly access them, if you have no access to C source code. There's no direct correspondance between a Java method and a C function.

Comment: Thank you! I still need to make sure about one thingm if the NDK don't provide the access to the lower C function (like it does in the OMX decoding sample, we can call OMX C function through NDK to decode the video), then we have no access to C function of android source code.